# Jackson ObjectMapper parsing of HashMap returns all fields = NULL

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am attempting to parse HashMap data into POJO using

```
Object parsedMessage = objectMapper.convertValue(receivedMessage, destinationClass);
```

where receivedMessage is a HashMap (earlier parsed from JSON) and containing fields of various types - Integer, Boolean, String, LinkedHashMap.

I have defined ***destinationClass*** so that it contains ***some*** of the fields found in HashMap keys, with exactly the same names as the keys (case-sensitive).

The instruction executes without an exception but all the fields in parsedMessage are **null**. What could be the reason? The similar instructions work just fine in other place of code.

Comment: which your code and POJO class ?

Comment: the simple "Id: 1" key-value pair in HashMap does not gets converted to Integer Id =1  as an object field @Jerry06

Comment: i saw it worked with jackson 2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it.

Turns out, regardless how your Java fields in ***destinationClass*** are named, Jackson (at least, by default) assumes that it is named in lowerCamelCase. 
So if your hashmap has "YourField" and your POJO has the same "YourField", then it will NOT work **if you do not use lowerCamelCase from the start on both ends**! (and if you parse serialized .NET JSON, you will end up with UpperCamelCase).

Because Jackson **assumes that your POJO's "YourField" is named "yourField" for matching!**

To fix this, either:

your HashMap keys must be lowerCamelCase.

OR

Create Mapper with case-insensitive behaviour

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
return om;
```

OR

for clarity you can use annottaions in POJO (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations)

```
   @JsonProperty("YourField")
   private String YourField;
```

NOTE: if you want to do some sort of "Tolerant Reader" (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TolerantReader.html) with partial parsing, you may find class-based annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
so you will not get exceptions if you are trying to parse the field that you did not described.